# about the independent event A and B it is known that p(A|B)=0.2 AND P(B|A)=0.5 COMPUTE probabality of P(AUB)?

Tags: probability

[what is the answer of this please quick as possible ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJCu0.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJCu0.png)

Comment: As quick as possible?  Why?  That sounds suspiciously like you are in the middle of a timed exam.

Comment: not absolute that but i prepare to exam and thank you

Comment: I will give you a hint but not a solution.  $A$ and $B$ are independent which tells you quite a bit about $p(A\mid B)$ and about $p(A\cap B)$

Comment: p(A ∩ B )= p(A).P(B) AND P(A|B)= P(A∩B)/P(B) HOW TO MATCH BETWEEN THOSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said: $p(A\cap B)=p(A)p(B)$ (independence) and $p(A\cap B)=p(A|B)p(B)$ (definition). So $p(A|B)=p(A)$. Similarly $p(B)=p(B|A)$.

So that gives you $p(A)=0.2,p(B)=0.5$ and $p(A\cap B)=0.1$.

Hence $p(A\text{ or }B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)=0.6$.

Comment: thank you very much . can you help me in this what is the answer of this ?
determine the gradient of the function belwo at point (0,0) .
 x^2-2y^2-4y+6